# TFS 2013 build - uploading build output to servier via FTP

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, ftp

I'm hoping someone can help. I've started using the [Community TFS Build Extensions](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), in particular the FTP activity. I followed the [documentation here](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20Ftp%20Activity) and got to grips with the it pretty easily. I'm encountering one major problem though.

My Web app has a basic enough structure:

[image: Web appstructure]

I start by creating the FindMatchingFile activity which places the files in the drop location into an IEnumberable variable called **FilesToFTP** :

```
String.Format("{0}\**\*.*", BuildDetail.DropLocation)
```

When I iterate through the variable and print out the results, all seems correct:

```
G:\builds\Build.1203\CredentialManagement\bin\BusLogic.dll
G:\builds\Build.1203\CredentialManagement\css\style.css
G:\builds\Build.1203\CredentialManagement\AppError.aspx
......
G:\builds\Build.1203\CredentialManagement\Web.config
```

etc etc.

The problem is, when I pass that IEnumerable to the Ftp activity (converting it to a string array), it FTP uploads all the files on the server however **it doesn't keep the directory structure** of my Web app. It just piles all the output (dlls, aspx etc) into one directory. See the following two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can use the FTP activity to upload all the output from the drop location recursively? I feel like I'm doing something simple wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP activity in TFS Build Extensions doesn't upload files recursively.

I think it would be a good value addition to the activity. Please create a request for the project and we will add in it. For now, you can go around it by calling the Ftp activity recursively for each directory and setting the RemoteDirectory for each.

Comment: Thanks for your response Hamid. I figured that _might_ be the case so I already took precautions and wrote up logic to do just that.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I think your suggestion is a good value addition that can be done in this activity.